# Release Configuration does not link header libraries in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-4.2

I am working on an application which is working properly in Debug configuration.

But when I am trying to build it in Release mode, its showing me list of errors specifically not finding header libraries.

Is there any extra settings I have to do for it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Check the build settings of your application. (In XCode3: Project -> Project Settings -> Build tab).

You may set options for 'All Configurations' or for individual configuration separately. Check the entries you have for 'Header Search Paths' in Release versus Debug.

Comment: i have checked it. There is no entries for "Header Serach Paths" in debug and release mode as well..!!

Comment: What are the missing headers? If it is about standard iOS headers, maybe your installation is incomplete or Base SDK set to some iOS version you do not have installed?

Comment: Also, your question is not clear: Do you have an error during compilation (the header files cannot be found) or during linking (the libraries cannot be found)?

Comment: At building time, I am getting error "No such file or directory"

Comment: Did you get the error during compilation or during linking? Is the header file or the lib not found? Also, in the build console, you may scroll to the top and then press on the 'lines' icon next to the number of errors. This will give you complete output from the compiler and linker that you may cut&paste when reporting errors.

Answer (score 0):

See the header paths settings in dubug and release mode .Make them same in both configurations